# Which memory management is easiest to program - CoCo 3 or C128/Apple //e?

Tags: commodore-64, programming, commodore-128, coco

As the 8-bit systems hit their peak in the mid-1980s, breaking the 64K barrier was all the rage. Commodore, Apple, Atari, and Tandy all shipped new 8-bit machines that came standard with 128K. Of course, this introduced the need for new memory controllers and programming models, since all these machines had only a 64K address range.

I know that Tandy's solution with the Coco 3 was using Dynamic Address Translation, and the unexpanded 128K Coco 3 presented as 16x8K pages. Commodore and Apple used bank switching to select one or the other 64K memory bank. I think Atari did the same, but I'm not sure.

My gut feeling is using the 128K with the coarse bank switching approach would not work very well. Swapping code/data pages around using DAT seems like a more feasible and familiar programming model to me.

I'll go a little over the top perhaps, and ask: Was the bank switching approach basically a **gimmick** that allowed the Commodore and Apple machines to be marketed as having 128K, even though the additional memory was not very useful (beyond a RAM disk)?

Likewise, is it true that the DAT approach as provided by the Coco 3 is a superior way to expand memory above 64K and keep the programming relatively simple?

(A great answer would probably include an example of how to use DAT effectively, and which isn't possible with bank switching).

Comment: What do you mean by "easy"? Fewer instructions? If it's "ease of use for x" this might be too subjective.

Comment: I would say that neither approach was any good. Application programmers, it seems, hate having to think about memory management at any level (hence the popularity of garbage collected languages)  never mind what banks or segments are where. The 80386 had a great segmented architecture which allowed you to neatly partition your code from your data and stack, but everybody just set all the segments to start at 0 and cover the entire 4Gb address range.  People like simple flat address spaces.

Comment: I asked which is "easier". It's intended as compare and contrast each model. I could substitute which is "useful" if my hunch about bank switching being basically a gimmick is correct.

Comment: How different was the CoCo3's address translation to bank switching on CP/M+ and the Amstrad computers, where 16K pages were swapped in and out at the same address?

Comment: @scruss Probably pretty similar in that it's just pages being switched on the CoCo, not the entire 64KB address space at once.

Comment: @BrianH I know you asked which is easier. That's why I posted as a comment, not an answer. I was not trying to answer your question just posting a general comment.

Comment: @JeremyP I understand. I'm simply trying to explain myself, what I'm looking for. I want to craft a question that's straightforward, but maybe I'm being too "wordy".

Comment: No, the wording is fine as far as I'm concerned. It's absolutely clear to me what it is about.

Comment: Both techniques you describe are both properly referred to as bank switching. The very name "bank" suggests multiple of blocks of memory  to switch between, not just two. The Commodore 128 bank switching scheme wasn't quite as simple as you describe, you could set up an unbanked region at the bottom and/or top of memory. As far as I know Apple II bank switching schemes used a single bank of size of 16K at the end of memory. The TRS-80 Color Computer 3 split the entire 64k address space in to 32 8K banks.The later is obviously the most flexible of the schemes, but not necessarily the easiest.

Comment: @RossRidge Good info there. The bank switching==DAT terminology issue would be great to sort out. My feeling is that bank switching is a very "loose" term, and DAT is a fairly specific technique, that falls within the rubric of the loose term.

Comment: Atari used 4x16K banks at $4000 in the Atari 130XE

Comment: @BrianH I don't think "Dynamic Address Translation" is a particularly useful term here. Technically, all bank switching implementations dynamically translate addresses, while on the other hand the term is mostly used in connection to IBM mainframes and the virtual memory design they pioneered and now used in modern general purpose CPUs. The CoCo 3 comes the closest to something resembling virtual memory, but falls short. (And I should correct something I said earlier, the CoCo 3 actually has 8 8K memory banks.)

Comment: @JeremyP "Application programmers, it seems, hate having to think ..." Application programmers today don't *have* to think about anything performance-related, most of the time. If their code wastes 99% of the memory, disk space, and CPU cycles it occupies, it doesn't matter. Computing in the 1970s was a different world, both for micros and high performance computing. Consider that the even Cray-1's clock speed was only 0.08 GHz!

Comment: @RossRidge: The Apple //e and above use much more complicated bank switching than you describe. The following regions can be banked for reading, writing or both: pages 0 & 1 & D0-FF (D0-DF has it's own banking: 2 in Main and 2 in Aux), just graphics page ranges, or all of memory - except for the CX pages which have both motherboard ROM (and RAM in the //c+) and peripheral card RAM/ROM per card at CX and shared at C8-CF. It's a nightmare, frankly. I'd like to know more about Coco 3 DAT.

Comment: @NickWestgate Well, I was ignoring the banking of ROM, I/O and video accesses which seemed to be outside of the scope of the question. Those add additional complexity to all of the computers mentioned.

Comment: Sounds like OP already has his answer.  Seems biased towards DAT.  Besides, this is an opinion based answer.

Comment: I can think of much easier '80s-era schemes than either, and neither is particularly unique to the specific hardware that constitutes the question. There's an Atari 2600 bank switching scheme that spots JSRs and RTSs and pages automatically based on the target; there are schemes elsewhere that watch the SYNC line and make different RAM pools available depending on the current location of the program counter; there are operating systems like Acorn's that hide all the mechanics for you.

Comment: ... and I guess that later machines with segments do much the same work as bank switching. E.g. the classic 68k Mac OS loads programs in 16kb chunks (if memory serves) and swaps those in and out on demand. So your program is a bunch of 16kb islands just as if it were in an eight-bit bank switcher.

Comment: I throw in the fact the Commodore REUs (1700, 1764 and 1750) had been considered more useful than their 3rd party successor GeoRAM because of its DMA controller (as opposed to the paging mechanism GeoRAM used).

Answer (score 10):

Neither CoCo nor Retro-Apples are my specific area of expertise - I'll try to answer from a more European viewpoint. Concepts and technical solutions are similar, however.

Basically, *all* the technologies you describe that allow the adaptation of more memory than the CPU would normally be able to address are, at least in my terminology, denoted under the general term **Bank Switching**. The implementations of such mechanisms, did, however, differ in terms of *memory granularity* (that is, size of banks - Which was very often selected as 16kB, which seems kind of appropriate for 64kB address space) and *memory flexibility* (that is, which bank can be superimposed onto which area in the addressable memory space). The term *bank* is also kind of unspecific - Some vendors referred to a bank as the *source memory area* in the larger address space, some others used the term for the *target memory area* in the CPU's address space.

Some computers also had the limitations that parts of the address space were dedicated to specific purposes like memory-mapped I/O (not on the Z80, typically) and screen memory (the ZX Spectrum 128, for example, always had screen memory fixed at 0x4000 and above). Other computers like the Enterprise could feed the screen more flexibly from selectable memory pages or, like the Cambridge Z88, didn't have screen or other dedicated memory areas in a traditional sense at all.

Some examples:

The [Cambridge Z88](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cambridge_Z88) is able to address 3.5MB of RAM that is logically segmented into max. 256 16kB pages. Each of those pages can be mapped onto any of four *banks* of Z80 address space. *Granularity:* 16kB, *Flexibility:* full. (Being a kind of early "notebook computer", much of this memory area was normally used for storage in battery-buffered RAM, EPROM or, later, Flash memory)

The [Enterprise 128](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_(computer)) uses a very similar scheme, 16kB page size, max. addressable memory 4MB, page/bank size 16kB, full flexibility. Like the Z88, the Enterprise provides ROM routines for linear addressing of data and code and moving data and code out and about within the larger address space and thus makes bank switching extremely transparent to the programmer.

The [ZX Spectrum 128](http://www.old-computers.com/museum/computer.asp?c=35) ("Toastrack") had a much more limited banking logic. Like the above, it used 16kB pages, and divided its 128kB RAM + 16kb (48k "compatibility" ROM) + 16kB (128k "new" ROM) into 16kB slices. It did, however, have limited flexibility in what pages could be mapped into what bank in the Z80 address space: The lower 16kB bank could only be occupied by either one of the 16kB ROMs (So, that area was dedicated to ROM and made the Toastrack CP/M incapable, unlike later Spectrums), the next bank was fixed for screen memory pages and could only map pages 5 and 7 of the 128kBytes of RAM. Bank 3 was fixed and could not be paged in or out at all, and only Bank 4 could actually receive any of the 8 16kB RAM segments. The original Toastrack ROM did not provide a lot of support for bank switching - You basically have the mechanisms to influence the pages, but beyond that, for example, to move memory contents from one bank to another, you were on your own and had to decide which pages to page in and where.

[image: Picture from http://www.robeesworld.com/blog/35/loading_zx_spectrum_snapshots_off_microdrives_part_two]

Later (Amstrad-made) ZX Spectrum models like the +2 and +3 had a more flexible banking scheme.

Computers based on the 6502 or similar CPUs had more challenges with large memory and bank switching than Z80-based computers. The 6502 zero page (or rather, the lower 1kB) is a crucial memory area that cannot be easily moved about in the address space as it holds address information for indirect addressing and other crucial information like the fix-addressed and size-limited CPU stack. Also, 6502 and similar CPUs typically use memory-mapped I/O, so we have another area that needs to fit into the 64k address space. You could easily argue that memory banking **had to be** more complicated on such a CPU than on the Z80.

The C128 MMU had special mechanisms to relocate this area and always kept the lower 1k mapped to the same RAM.  A C128 also had the additional challenge that it needed to orchestrate and accommodate two CPUs - the 8510 and the Z80 with the same memory.

I am not a C128 expert, but understand the following: The C128 had provisions to be able to cope with a maximum amount of 256kB of RAM internally and used sort of fixed memory configurations. While the zero page+ was handled specifically and always paged in from bank 1, you could either have 0x03ff-0xffff all RAM from Bank 0 (one half of the 128k available), or all RAM from Bank 1 (the other half of the 128k), or 16k from Bank 1 and the rest occupied with ROM and either I/O or character ROM. On top of that, the MMU had a *common RAM* feature, that allowed to partially "override" the RAM configuration in a way that would configure certain memory areas of pre-selected sizes (1k-16k) to always map to Bank 1 memory. All in all, extremely complicated...

With respect to ease of programming, the "fixed page size, fully flexible mapping" approach definitely sounds likethe most simple, easy to understand and program way of doing things on a very low level. Juggling with the C128 MMU and paging registers on a low level doesn't look like fun to me. If, however, the on-board ROM supported you in providing calls and data access routines into the whole memory like the C128 (and, for example, the Enterprise and Z88, where you basically handed in a register triple instead of a register pair to the ROM routines in order to linearly address memory in the 4MB range) did, all of those complications basically became rather transparent to the programmer, so from an applications programmer view, I wouldn't really prefer one over the other.

Comment: Technically the C128 MMU could have allowed up to 1MB (16 banks of 64k) but that ignores the IO mappings and introduces other issues (and they saved some money by not wiring up all the selector pins anyway).  There are tutorials online on expanding a 128 up to the full 1MB.

Comment: ZX Spectrum 128k never had any bank switching in 0x4000..0x7fff area. Page 5 was there all the time.